# Create aging debtor query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table with the following structure

```
AccountId --- TransactionDate --- Debit ---- Credit
=========     ===============     =====      ======
xyz           01-01-2021           0.00 ---- 10.00
xyz           15-01 -2022         10.00 ----  0.00
xyz           06-02 -2022         30.00 ----  0.00
===================================================
```

I need to create a debtor aging report in the following format

```
AccountId   15DaysAgo   7 DaysAgo  Total
=========   ========    ========== ======
xyz          0.00        30.00      30.00
```

I found this query  and trying to use it but not sure how I can do a running balance to apply as balance amount. BalanceAmount is (debit - credit) but if I sum them then I get mysql error.

```
SELECT accountid,
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), transactiondate) BETWEEN 1 AND 7, balanceAmount, 0)) AS age7Days,
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), transactiondate) BETWEEN 8 AND 16, balanceAmount, 0)) AS age15Days,
SUM(balanceAmount) AS totalBalance
FROM billing  bill
WHERE
bill.balanceAmount  > 0
GROUP BY accountid
ORDER BY totalBalance DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried putting "debit - credit" instead of balanceAmount? You may need to modify your WHERE clause to "WHERE SUM (debit) > SUM(credit) "

Comment: SUM(balanceAmount) AS totalBalance - represnts balance as at current date right? if so total doen;t seem an appropriate header. And 'a running balance' isn't neccessary you are just summing to time points.

Comment: @Kendle thank you that(debit -credit) did the trick. I was trying with (SUM(debit) - SUM(Credit)) and it was creating invalid use of group error.

Comment: Please vote for the comment if it helped. Thank you